# Does JIT and JAVA interpreter perform their task together hand by hand or JIT completes it works first?

Tags: java, jvm, interpreter, jit

As per my understanding, if Java interpreter alone starts executing bytecode line by line the performance will be slow, hence JIT comes in the picture for code optimization for faster execution of code.

JIT compiler optimizes the code and java interpreter translates the optimized code line by line.And as JIT runs only at runtime,so we don't get any binary output.Once interpreter translates , binary code is produced.

---Now my question is, does JIT and JAVA interpreter works together ?
or,
jit compiler works at first, and then java interpreter starts working?

Please confirm this?

Comment: There are no lines in Java bytecode, hence an interpreter doesn’t execute “line by line”, but instruction by instruction. Further, your idea of “interpreter translates” is strange, as at the beginning of your question, you got it right, the interpreter doesn’t translate, but *executes*. It’s unclear, why you suddenly change to the concept of an interpreter doing the JIT compiler’s work in the middle of your question.

Comment: I am a beginner. Thank you very much for the answer. It has been immensely helpful explaination.I dont know I am studying through google search and many where I found the term 'interpreter translates'...thanks for correcting that it executes but not translates.

Comment: Basically, both perform different tasks, working on the same source data. The interpreter executes the byte code directly whereas the JIT compiler translates it into native code for later execution (the term JIT compiler originally only refers to this translation task, but today, optimizing and translating are usually considered inseparable tasks). So while they are doing different things, there is some kind of interaction, e.g. there must be a protocol defining how the interpreter stops its work to switch to the native code generated by the JIT compiler and how the native code switches back…

Answer (score 0):

When a Java runtime starts up, it will run bytecode with an interpreter. As methods are called repeatedly, they will be compiled to a faster version. If they are called even more, they will be compiled even faster.

Answer (score 0):

When java runs your program, it interprets the bytecode and runs it. If it detects that a particular bit of code is run very frequently, the JIT compiler will kick in and the bytecode will be compiled into platform-specific code for whatever platform the code is running on (i.e. machine code).

For code that has been compiled by the JIT compiler, the compiled code is used directly instead of the bytecode, hence no interpreting is necessary (which is why it's faster).

There's a one-time performance hit in performing the JIT compilation, so that's why java only does it for code that's run frequently.